# What do Grassmann-valued terms in operators really mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, grassmann-numbers

I've read (for example, ch. 5 of Piers Coleman's book on Many Body Physics), that a simple general formulation of a fermionic driven harmonic oscillator problem is:

$$H = H_0 + V(t)$$

$$H_0 = E_0 c^\dagger c$$

$$V(t) = \bar{\eta}(t)c(t) + c^\dagger(t) \eta(t),$$

In which $\eta(t)$ and $\bar{\eta}(t)$ are Grassmann numbers, i.e.   $\eta(t)\bar{\eta}(t) = -\bar{\eta}(t)\eta(t)$.

(the time dependent part can be small if one wants to consider this as a perturbation theory problem, but it doesn't matter here)

I'm wondering what this "really" means, and how to reconcile this with perhaps a more basic understanding of quantum mechanics.

For example, what about the Hamiltonian (which I believe is the same thing) in the basis $|0\rangle = (0\;\;1)^T$ and  $|1\rangle = (1\;\;0)^T$

\begin{equation}H = \begin{pmatrix} E_0 & z(t) \\ z^*(t)& 0 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

What is the relationship between the $z(t)$ here and the $\eta(t)$ above?

My guess is that $\eta(t)$ really means $z(t)\eta$, where $z(t)$ is just a complex number and $\eta$ is a Grassmann generator so that $\eta(t)$ is Grassmann odd.  But how does one get this from the matrix form above?  Also, I'm not sure in this case how $V(t)$ is even Hermitian, unless $\bar{\eta}$ is to be interpreted as the complex conjugate of $\eta$?